# Is the IPv4 packet here smaller than the Ethernet minimum packet size, and, if so, by how much? What if the packet is IPv6 with no extens

Tags: networking, tcp, ipv6

A packet contains an IPv6 header with no options and a 20-byte TCP header. Is the IPv6 packet here smaller than the Ethernet minimum packet size, and, if so, by how much?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the example that you give is smaller than the minimum Ethernet *frame* size; *packet* refers to things at Layer 3 and above, frames to layer 2.

The minimum frame size is 64 bytes.  An Ethernet frame consists of 14 bytes of Ethernet header and a 4 byte trailer (Frame Check Sequence).  This leaves 46 bytes (64 - 14 - 4).  Note that you will not be able to see the trailer in any typical sniffer; the network card will not deliver it to the networks stack of the operating system.

The TCP/IP packet that you have described would be 40 bytes in length.  This means that the remaining 6 bytes will consist of padding.

I leave it to you to apply the same logic to figuring out the size of an IPv6 header/packet.

Comment: The ethernet frame has a _four_-octet FCS, not a two-byte trailer. An ethernet packet includes a seven-octet preamble, and a one-octet SoF delimiter. The minimum ethernet payload is 46 octets (assuming no 802.1Q tag), or 42 octets (with an 802.1Q tag). The payload is padded to reach the minimum.

Comment: Yep.  Thanks. ;). Couldn't get the reference to load and did it from memory, @RonMaupin

Comment: I didn't copy/paste anything. I know that stuff by heart.